# How to Create a 3 level graph using NEO4J using JSON Array of Objects

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create a graph using neo4j which gives me a graph of the terms in the "JavaScript" array of the following JSON data, along with relationships pointing to unique "relatedTerms" nodes.

Here is my JSON data:

```
{
 "JavaScript": [
    {
      "termName": "asm.js",
      "link": "/terms/javascript/asmjs",
      "info": "A subset of JavaScript. Effectively describes a safe virtual machine for memory-unsafe languages like C or C++. It can be used as a low-level, efficient target language for compilers.",
      "relatedTerms": [
        {
          "name": "JavaScript",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/549"
        },
        {
          "name": "C",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/470"
        },
        {
          "name": "C++",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/860"
        },
        {
          "name": "compilers",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/390"
        }
      ],
      "category": "JavaScript"
    },
    {
      "termName": "Cycle.js",
      "link": "/terms/javascript/cyclejs",
      "info": "JavaScript framework for a predictable code. Builds on functional and reactive streams. Describes an app as a simple function taking an event stream as input and outputting an event stream.",
      "relatedTerms": [
        {
          "name": "JavaScript",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/549"
        }
      ],
      "category": "JavaScript"
    },
    {
      "termName": "Derby",
      "link": "/terms/javascript/derby",
      "info": "Server component which is written on top of Node.js. It's is a server-side application with rich real-time data synchronization technology such used in google docs.",
      "relatedTerms": [
        {
          "name": "Node.js",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/595"
        }
      ],
      "category": "JavaScript"
    },
    {
      "termName": "Express.js",
      "link": "/terms/javascript/expressjs",
      "info": "Lightweight, efficient middleware and routing framework. Express.js is best known as another quarter of the MEAN (MongoDB, Express, AngularJS and Node) software stack, and is the most popular Node.js framework.",
      "relatedTerms": [
        {
          "name": "MEAN",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/361"
        },
        {
          "name": "MongoDB",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/868"
        },
        {
          "name": "AngularJS",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/47"
        },
        {
          "name": "Node",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/595"
        }
      ],
      "category": "JavaScript"
    },
    {
      "termName": "Flow",
      "link": "/terms/javascript/flow",
      "info": "A static type checker for JavaScript. Integrates with the code editor by checking changes and analyzing correctness of the code. Provides context as to what is wrong with the code.",
      "relatedTerms": [
        {
          "name": "JavaScript",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/549"
        }
      ],
      "category": "JavaScript"
    },
    {
      "termName": "Hapi",
      "link": "/terms/javascript/hapi",
      "info": "Web framework for building web applications, APIs and services. Hapi was created around the idea that configuration is better than code, that business logic must be isolated from the transport layer.",
      "relatedTerms": [
        {
          "name": "APIs",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/206"
        }
      ],
      "category": "JavaScript"
    },
    {
      "termName": "Koa",
      "link": "/terms/javascript/koa",
      "info": "Callback-less, lightweight middleware framework for Node.js to build efficient web applications and APIs. Koa.js efficiently uses generators to deal with callbacks and increase error-handling capabilities.",
      "relatedTerms": [
        {
          "name": "Node.js",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/595"
        },
        {
          "name": "API",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/206"
        }
      ],
      "category": "JavaScript"
    },
    {
      "termName": "MEAN",
      "link": "/terms/javascript/mean",
      "info": "A full stack JavaScript solution that refers to the first letters of the four components of a solution for building dynamic websites: MongoDB, a NoSQL database; Express.js, a web applications framework; Angular.js, a JavaScript MVC framework for web apps; Node.js, a software platform for scalable server-side and networking applications.",
      "relatedTerms": [
        {
          "name": "JavaScript",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/549"
        },
        {
          "name": "MongoDB",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/868"
        },
        {
          "name": "NoSQL",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/951"
        },
        {
          "name": "Express.js",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/392"
        },
        {
          "name": "Angular.js",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/47"
        },
        {
          "name": "MVC",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/201"
        },
        {
          "name": "Node.js",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/595"
        }
      ],
      "category": "JavaScript"
    },
    {
      "termName": "Meteor",
      "link": "/terms/javascript/meteor",
      "info": "JavaScript framework built on top of Node.js with MongoDB as its database driver. With Node.js and Meteor, you’re using JavaScript everywhere, and data is synced through the use of WebSockets, a protocol that allows an interactive communication between server and browser.",
      "relatedTerms": [
        {
          "name": "Node.js",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/595"
        },
        {
          "name": "MongoDB",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/868"
        },
        {
          "name": "JavaScript",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/549"
        },
        {
          "name": "WebSockets",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/1046"
        }
      ],
      "category": "JavaScript"
    },
    {
      "termName": "Node.js",
      "link": "/terms/javascript/nodejs",
      "info": "One of the most popular JavaScript frameworks which eases the work of building web applications. By far the fastest growing language in use. Runs on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS. The use of Node.js is mainly for full stack, front-end and back-end.",
      "relatedTerms": [
        {
          "name": "JavaScript",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/549"
        },
        {
          "name": "Windows",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/1373"
        },
        {
          "name": "Linux",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/558"
        },
        {
          "name": "Node.js",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/595"
        }
      ],
      "category": "JavaScript"
    },
    {
      "termName": "Oracle JET",
      "link": "/terms/javascript/oracle_jet",
      "info": "Oracle JavaScript Extension Toolkit. A modular toolkit based on modern JavaScript, CSS3 and HTML5 design and development principles. Created for developers who work on applications that consume and interact with Oracle products and services.",
      "relatedTerms": [

      ],
      "category": "JavaScript"
    },
    {
      "termName": "Restify",
      "link": "/terms/javascript/restify",
      "info": "A Node.js module built specifically to enable to build correct REST web services. It borrows heavily from express as that is more or less the de facto API for writing web applications on top of Node.js.",
      "relatedTerms": [
        {
          "name": "Node.js",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/595"
        },
        {
          "name": "REST",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/524"
        },
        {
          "name": "API",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/206"
        }
      ],
      "category": "JavaScript"
    },
    {
      "termName": "Sails",
      "link": "/terms/javascript/sails",
      "info": "Sails.js wraps express and provides another higher level for doing things like connecting to the DB, auto-generating input pages, etc. Especially suitable for creating chat apps or multiplayer games.",
      "relatedTerms": [
        {
          "name": "DB",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/415"
        }
      ],
      "category": "JavaScript"
    },
    {
      "termName": "Seneca",
      "link": "/terms/javascript/seneca",
      "info": "Microservices toolkit for Node.js. Helps to write an organized code that can be scaled and deployed at any time. Organizes the business logic of an app.",
      "relatedTerms": [
        {
          "name": "Node.js",
          "link": "/terms/go_to_term/595"
        }
      ],
      "category": "JavaScript"
    }
  ]
  }
```

My Expected Result looks like: [image: Expected]

The following is my Query:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///js.json") YIELD value
UNWIND value.JavaScript AS item
FOREACH(js IN item |
CREATE(cat:Category{name:js.termName})
FOREACH(rt in item.relatedTerms|
CREATE(rtt:RelatedTerms{name:rt.name})
MERGE (cat)-[r:RELATESTO]->(rtt)))
```

And here is my Actual Result: [image: Actual]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching the CREATE statements for MERGE statements. In Cypher, MERGE will check to see if a pattern exists and create it if it does not. CREATE will create a new pattern every time, even if a pattern like it already exists in the graph.

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///js.json") YIELD value
UNWIND value.JavaScript AS item
MERGE (cat:Category {name:item.termName})
WITH cat, item
UNWIND item.relatedTerms AS subitem 
MERGE (rt:RelatedTerm {name:subitem.name})
MERGE (cat)-[:RELATES_TO]->(rt)
RETURN *
```

Comment: ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/2owiI.png ) Thanks for the help sir, but i am still not getting my expected result can you help me to change any logic if any

Comment: I updated the query in my answer to use two unwind statements instead of a foreach.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2XzS.png Thank you, but how can i remove the duplicate nodes ?